Почему сервер VMware работает хуже сервера Openstack?
У меня есть два сервера с Ubuntu. Один в Openstack и один в VMware. На обоих одинаково настроен один и тот же сервис в Docker контейнере. Настройка систем одинаковая на обоих серверах - одинаковое количество ядер и памяти. Сервис - это небольшое FastAPI приложение.
Проблема в том, что при среднем количестве запросов на сервер (около 30 в секунду) сервисы отлично работают на обоих серверах. Но если нагрузка повышается и запросов становится около 100 в секунду на сервер, то на VMware сервере они выполняются значительно дольше (5+ секунд), чем на Openstack сервере.
Не знаете с чем это может быть связано?
Проверил потребляемые ресурсы докера, логи сервисов, сравнил версии, но не вижу, в чем именно проблема. Может я что-то упускаю?
